# Bucket sort and User input

Tags: c++, c++14, bucket-sort

Here's the problem I'm working on: a user gives me an unspecified number of points on a standard x,y coordinate plane, where 0 < x^2 + y^2 <= 1. (x squared plus y squared, just for clarity).
Here is an example of the input:

```
0.2 0.38
0.6516 -0.1
-0.3 0.41
-0.38 0.2
```

From there, I calculate the distance of those points from the origin, (0, 0). Here is the function I use to find the distance and push it into a vector of doubles, B.

```
void findDistance(double x = 0, double y = 0) { 
    double x2 = pow(x, 2);
    double y2 = pow(y, 2);
    double z = x2 + y2;
    double final = sqrt(z);
    B.push_back(final);
```

}

Then, I want to bucket sort vector B, where there are n buckets for n points. Here is my current build of the bucketSort:

```
void bucketSort(double arr[], int n)
{
    vector<double> b[n];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       int bi = n*arr[i];
       b[bi].push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
       sort(b[i].begin(), b[i].end());

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++)
          arr[index++] = b[i][j];
}
```

My problem is I can't get bucketSort to work without crashing. I get a windows message saying the program has stopped working. Now, I know the function works, but only when I initialize the vector and fill it at the same time. This is an example of a call that works:

```
double arr[] = {0.707107, 0.565685, 0.989949, 0.848528 };
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
bucketSort(arr, n);
```

So far, I've yet to find any other format for calling and initializing the vector that the function will accept and run. I need to find a way to take the points, computer the distances, and sort the distances. Current main that I'm plugging in and getting as a backfire:

```
int main(){
int number;
while (cin >> number){ 
    A.push_back(number);    }
int q = 0; double r = 0; double d = 0;
while (q < (A.size() - 1)){
    findDistance(A[q], A[q+1]);
    q += 2;
}
double arr[B.size()]; copy(B.begin(), B.end(), arr);
int n = (sizeof(B) + sizeof(B[0])) / sizeof(B[0]);
bucketSort(arr, n);
int w = 0; 
while (w < y){ cout << arr[w] << endl; w++; }
```

The arr copy was created in some strange debugging attempt: sorry if unclear. Results of distance function stored in B, copied into arr, and arr is what's attempted to be sorted. The user inputs are given through the command prompt, using the syntax listed in the beginning. Output should be something like:

```
0.42941
0.49241
0.50804
0.65923
```

If anyone can offer suggestions of edits to either of functions that would make it work, the assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us what didn't work.

Comment: Did a slight edit. Hope that helps.

Comment: You need to provide [something that others can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't debug code that we can't see.

Comment: If x and y are both < 1 it doesn't follow that all values in B are less than one (they could be up to sqrt(2)). Assuming `arr` is made from `B` somehow (this wasn't clear) then `n*arr[i]` could be bigger than `n` and overflow your `b` array.

Comment: Edited for clarity, hopefully. @TheDark, valid point, but that was a typo on my part. Changed/clarified that at the beginning now. 0 < x^2 + y^2 <= 1. Don't know if that changes your suggestion or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few issues to work on:

Your input loop will stop when it reads a non-integer. Change `number` to `double`

Your size calculation

```
int n = (sizeof(B) + sizeof(B[0])) / sizeof(B[0]);
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but `sizeof` on a vector is not what you want. I think replacing this with:

```
int n = B.size();
```

is what you want.

I am not sure why you needed to convert the vector to an array to do the bucket sort - much easier to just pass the vector through to the bucket sort, then the size comes with the vector.

Change the `bucketSort` function to take a reference to a vector:

```
void bucketSort(vector<double> &arr)
{
   int n = B.size();
   ...
```

and just pass B into the function. The rest of the code should be the same.

Also a portability note: not every compiler supports variable sized arrays, you are better off sticking with `vector` wherever possible.

Comment: That appears to have worked entirely. Thank you so much, and sorry for the aggravating way I kept wording my question.